# How can I remove the Pulse news feature from my LinkedIn homepage?

Tags: linkedin

I'd like to remove the Pulse news feature from my LinkedIn homepage. The [LinkedIn help page](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5263) says:

> The Pulse news feature cannot be removed from the homepage. [Learn how
>   to customize the channels and Influencers you follow.](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5008/ft/eng)

Is there any other way like browser extensions to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The LinkedIn source has changed - after experimenting, I believe the new incantation to use in AdBlock is:

```
www.linkedin.com##LI[class="feed-item linkedin-recommend-pulse digested actor-verb"]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like the [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) addin for Firefox. Then you need to write a script that hides the content of the LI tag with an ID of "today-news-wrapper".

You could also do this (probably a bit easier) using [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or even [FoxReplace](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxreplace/).

Of course, those recommendations assume you are using Firefox as your browser, if using other browsers, you would need to try and find similar addons.

Use the Web Developer tools (usually made visible with F12) to see the structure of the web page so that you can work out what to hide.

Alternatively, click on the "All Updates" drop down at the top of the list, go to settings and unclick all the options. Dont know if that hides everything though and I'm not about to try I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1):

Install Adblock Plus 2.4.1. Go to `-> Filter Preferences -> Custom Filters-> Add filter group-> Add Filter` and paste these two lines

```
www.linkedin.com##LI[id="today-news-wrapper"][class="feed-item today-news-el tod-wrpr feed-item-insert"]
www.linkedin.com##LI[id="today-news-wrapper"][class="feed-item today-news-el tod-wrpr"]
```

Works for me. I use Firefox.

Comment: Also, even after adding the necessary ADP filters above, I suggest to **not** use the _See x new updates_ button. Use refresh or reload the LinkedIn page instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Greasemonkey script I just wrote for this purpose. It also removed the annoying prompts to update your profile every time you login.

https://gist.github.com/midwire/37accf6e2b7d8e6da199/raw/ad5bdb325306ac4d929d52ba8973ac32f5037aa9/Fix_Linkedin.user.js

Feel free to modify to suit your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

The latest (working) settings for your browser add-on ABP (Adblock Plus) in order to remove Pulse updates on your LinkedIn home page:

Add the following 2 lines (as new custom filters) to ABP:

```
www.linkedin.com##LI[class="feed-item linkedin-sponsor"]
www.linkedin.com##LI[class="feed-update pulse-recommend-article-rollup has-snippets"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter has changed yet again (funny how that seems to keep happening), here is the new ABP filter as of May 2016:

www.linkedin.com##LI.pulse-recommend-article-rollup

Answer (score 0):

This Google Chrome extension get rid of the entire LinkedIn (and Facebook) news feed: [Kill All News Feeds](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kill-all-news-feeds/efcpihmloomplhflpabplgdpddgoagpi?hl=en)